# Dependent variables role in Kmeans Clustering

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have two variables in my data which are dependent on each other.I need to perform K means clustering on my data set.Do I need to discard one variable before performing k means clustering or both the variables can be fed as input to the algorithm.Any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: Typically, clustering does *not* involve dependent variables. But this is not a *programming* question, hence it is arguably off-topic here; better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

If the relationship is very strong it literally should not make a difference.

Why don't you just try, and compare the results? Does it make a difference?